# select column value by custom priority

Tags: mysql, select

Mysql 5.7

I have a table with 3 columns

**ID** -> Primary Key

**STATUS** -> User Status

**MASTERID** -> Foreign Key

I need a select query which will return a Status of the user using below priority

**Verified**  -> **1** has the highest priority

**Reset**     -> **2** the second priority

**Created**   -> **3** has the least priority

```
ID STATUS       MASTERID

1   Created      1

2   Verified     1

3   Reset        1

4   Created      1
```

select query should return ***Verified***

```
ID STATUS       MASTERID

1  Reset         1

2  Reset         1
```

select query should return ***Reset*** as there is only one distinct status present

```
ID STATUS       MASTERID

1  Reset           1

2  Created         1

3  Verified        1
```

select query should return ***Verified*** as it has the highest priority

above records are an example of one user, likewise I need to fetch the status of each distinct user

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `order by` with `field()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by masterid order by field(status, 'Verified', 'Reset', 'Created') as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you only want the result for one master id:

```
select t.*
from t
where masterid = 1
order by field(status, 'Verified', 'Reset', 'Created') 
limit 1;
```

Of course, for the values that you have specified, you could replace `field()` with `status desc`.  However, this offers the more general solution.

EDIT:

In MySQL 5.7, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.masterid = t.masterid 
                    order by field(status, 'Verified', 'Reset', 'Created')
              limit 1
             );
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, your solution is correct but unfortunately, I am using Mysql 5.7 and this version doesn't support the window functions, Will be really helpful if you could help me here

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that MASTERID is the user and I have taken the liberty of creating some sample data. But really the OP (and that is you) should be the one creating the sample tables and data on a website such as db-fiddle.com if you are seriously looking for someone to answer your questions in the future. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

```
SELECT MASTERID,
  CASE
     WHEN RANKING = 1 THEN 'Created'
     WHEN RANKING = 2 THEN 'Reset'
     WHEN RANKING = 3 THEN 'Verified'
  END as STATUS
FROM (
    SELECT MASTERID, MAX(FIELD(STATUS, 'Created', 'Reset', 'Verified')) as RANKING
    FROM mytable
    GROUP bY MASTERID
) SQ;

| MASTERID | STATUS   |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | Verified |
| 2        | Reset    |
| 3        | Verified |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bdKPGff7B3QXhEqZvKsWAC/1)

If you want to also have an associated ID with the returned results, then:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t1
WHERE FIELD(STATUS, 'Created', 'Reset', 'Verified') = (
    SELECT MAX(FIELD(STATUS, 'Created', 'Reset', 'Verified')) FROM mytable t2
    WHERE t2.MASTERID = t1.MASTERID
) AND t1.ID = (
    SELECT MIN(t2.ID) FROM mytable t2
    WHERE t2.MASTERID = t1.MASTERID AND t2.STATUS = t1.STATUS
)


| ID  | STATUS   | MASTERID |
| --- | -------- | -------- |
| 2   | Verified | 1        |
| 5   | Reset    | 2        |
| 9   | Verified | 3        |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bdKPGff7B3QXhEqZvKsWAC/2)

Comment: thank you for answering and creating a sample table.